# Google is going to remove the PayPal trusted URL

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm currently working on a project, which uses **PayPal** for it's payments.
And I'm a bit concerned about this notification which Chrome trows.

**The SSL certificate used to load resources from https://www.paypalobjects.com will be distrusted in M70. Once distrusted, users will be prevented from loading these resources. See https://g.co/chrome/symantecpkicerts for more information.**

Any ideas how this should be replaced will be very appreciated!

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Did you ask PayPal?

Comment: Not yet, lol Dominik says it's expected that PayPall will upgrade their certificate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both Chrome and Firefox have announced that they will increase the level of trust provided by the certificate authorities. The mentioned certificate will therefore only work until March '18 but I assume that PayPal will renew this certificate eventually.
More can be read here: https://blog.qualys.com/ssllabs/2017/09/26/google-and-mozilla-deprecating-existing-symantec-certificates